# Notifications do not appear below Oreo

Tags: android, notifications

on test devices with version 7.0, notifications do not appear. The virtual tests are running fine.

I think the code handels oreo and lower, am I wrong?

```
public static String channelAufgabeID = "channelTaskID";
public static String channelNameAufgabe = "Task";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (Main.notificationsActive == true) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channelTask = new NotificationChannel(channelTaskID, channelNameTask, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channelTask.enableLights(true);
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channelTask);
            }
        }

        Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        repeatingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, repeatingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("YourWeek")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_status_bar_deiwo)
                .setContentText("You planned a task")
                .setChannelId(channelTaskID)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using a mipmap for small icon don't supported on older versions, try with a PNG for example

Comment: so I need to load the icon into a new resource folder, aside of mipmap? The icon itself is a png

Comment: I tried to change to drawables folder but didnt work